# Help with Json/jquery for Hightchart

Tags: jquery, json

I need to put that into json

```
  plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function() {
                        location.href = this.options.url;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

I tryed that, but i got this error message

```
options.plotOptions.series.point.event is undefined
click : function() {
```

My code:

```
   $.getJSON('http://' + document.domain + '/school/student/globaloverviewgraph/graphoverview', function(data){
                options = data;
                 options.plotOptions.series.point.events = {
                click  : function() {

                   location.href = this.options.url;
                }
              }
             chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
          });
        }
```

I dont know why my code don't work , I already do a json for an another option of hight chart and that work

///////////////////////////////////////////
One of my  working code for an other Hightchart options
////////////////////////////////////////////

(Working json/jquery code for an other hightchart option)

```
$.getJSON('http://' + document.domain + '/school/graph/generate/graph1', function(data){
        options = data;
            options.tooltip = {
            formatter: function() {
                var extrafield = this.series.options.extrafield;
                var extrafield2 = this.series.options.extrafield2;
                return '<b>' + 'Note: ' + this.y +' % <br/>' + '<b>Nom de l\'examen :</b>' + extrafield[this.point.x - 1] + '</b> <br/><b>Date:</b>'  + extrafield2[this.point.x - 1] +' <br/>';
            }
         }
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
```

from

```
   tooltip: {
         formatter: function() {
                   return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
               this.x +': '+ this.y +'Â°C';
         }
      },
```

///////////////////

Some one can help me please ???  Thx !

Updated  ,  work but now i got url of all of my bar

```
$.getJSON('http://' + document.domain + '/school/student/globaloverviewgraph/graphoverview', function(data){
        options = data;

         options.plotOptions = {

            series :{
                    point:{
                            events:{
                                click: function(){
                                    var extrafield2 = this.series.options.extrafield2;
                                     location.href = extrafield2;

                                }
                            }
                    }


    }
  }
 chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

});
}

Comment: I'm assuming you console.log(data) to make sure you have the object?

Comment: yes, I got the first part  of my data with a json request but my script  bug  at this  place   options.plotOptions.series.point.events = {
 ,   maybe my syntax code  was not   good

Answer (score 1):

plotOptions needs to be in an object so `{ plotOptions: ... }` right now you're assigning options = plotOptions:{} which is not valid.

Comment: So I need to remove  options.plotOptions ?

Comment: Well you need to json encode it the right way on the server side. Can you post your json output for both /school/student/globaloverviewgraph/graphoverview and /school/graph/generate/graph1 ? I'm suspecting you're not json encoding it right.

Answer (score 0):

```
 options.plotOptions.series.point.events = {
                click  : function() {

                   location.href = this.options.url;
                }
              }
```

The above code should work find. Make sure you have to write code in your page where you are testing.

Comment: always got an error :( ,  i tryed an other code ( look the end of my post (updated),   that work but i got the URL of all of my BAR column

Comment: @downVoter - Can you please explain me the reason?

Comment: down  vote it's not me , or maybe an error from  me... I just  put you a up vote

Edit:  No the down vote its not me , if I remove my up vote the -1 vote still here